# Solve a matrix product without computing the inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, matrix-decomposition, pseudoinverse

If I have these matrix relationship expressed as a factorization:

$$\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{B}\cdot\mathbf{C}$$

where they are  $\mathbf{A}\in\{0, 1\}^{m , n}$, $\mathbf{B}\in\{0, 1\}^{m , r}$ and $\mathbf{C}\in\{0, 1\}^{r , n}$.

What if I know $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{C}$ and I want to solve for $\mathbf{B}$? I suppose that the solution is not unique, how can I get several different values for $\mathbf{B}$ that satisfy the factorization?

I'd rather not involve pseudo-inverses (supposing I could use them)

Comment: Do you need to do this by hand, or do you need an algorithm, or do you want to prove a statement about how to do this? (sure the last two are similar but the last one is more work)

Comment: I guess you have heard of the Gauß algorithm.

Comment: I'd want an algorithm to generate the solution**s**

Comment: Are you guaranteed that such a factorization exists?

Comment: yes, I mean by construction